# Discrepancy in SSL Ciphers between Apache 2.2 and OpenSSL 1.0.1

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, openssl, mod-ssl

I'm running up-to-date `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` with `Apache 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4` and `OpenSSL 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.11`.

I have configured Apache to use ciphersuites list from https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Recommended_Ciphersuite

It looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /path/to/signed_certificate
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/intermediate_certificate
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /path/to/private/key
    SSLCACertificateFile    /path/to/all_ca_certs
    SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
    SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
    SSLCompression          off
</VirtualHost>
```

This command shows all the available `OpenSSL` ciphers.

```
# openssl ciphers -v 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK' |column -t

ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256    TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA    Enc=AESGCM(128)    Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256  TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH        Au=ECDSA  Enc=AESGCM(128)    Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384    TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA    Enc=AESGCM(256)    Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384  TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH        Au=ECDSA  Enc=AESGCM(256)    Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256      TLSv1.2  Kx=DH          Au=RSA    Enc=AESGCM(128)    Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256      TLSv1.2  Kx=DH          Au=DSS    Enc=AESGCM(128)    Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384      TLSv1.2  Kx=DH          Au=DSS    Enc=AESGCM(256)    Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384      TLSv1.2  Kx=DH          Au=RSA    Enc=AESGCM(256)    Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256        TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA    Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256      TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH        Au=ECDSA  Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA           SSLv3    Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA    Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA         SSLv3    Kx=ECDH        Au=ECDSA  Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384        TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA    Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384      TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH        Au=ECDSA  Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA           SSLv3    Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA    Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA         SSLv3    Kx=ECDH        Au=ECDSA  Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256          TLSv1.2  Kx=DH          Au=RSA    Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA             SSLv3    Kx=DH          Au=RSA    Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256          TLSv1.2  Kx=DH          Au=DSS    Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256          TLSv1.2  Kx=DH          Au=RSA    Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA             SSLv3    Kx=DH          Au=DSS    Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA             SSLv3    Kx=DH          Au=RSA    Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA1
AES128-GCM-SHA256              TLSv1.2  Kx=RSA         Au=RSA    Enc=AESGCM(128)    Mac=AEAD
AES256-GCM-SHA384              TLSv1.2  Kx=RSA         Au=RSA    Enc=AESGCM(256)    Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA              SSLv3    Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA    Enc=RC4(128)       Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA            SSLv3    Kx=ECDH        Au=ECDSA  Enc=RC4(128)       Mac=SHA1
SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA        SSLv3    Kx=SRP         Au=DSS    Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA        SSLv3    Kx=SRP         Au=RSA    Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA             SSLv3    Kx=DH          Au=DSS    Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256     TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH/ECDSA  Au=ECDH   Enc=AESGCM(128)    Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH/ECDSA  Au=ECDH   Enc=AESGCM(128)    Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256         TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH/ECDSA  Au=ECDH   Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256       TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH/ECDSA  Au=ECDH   Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA            SSLv3    Kx=ECDH/RSA    Au=ECDH   Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA          SSLv3    Kx=ECDH/ECDSA  Au=ECDH   Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA1
AES128-SHA256                  TLSv1.2  Kx=RSA         Au=RSA    Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA256
AES128-SHA                     SSLv3    Kx=RSA         Au=RSA    Enc=AES(128)       Mac=SHA1
SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA        SSLv3    Kx=SRP         Au=DSS    Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA        SSLv3    Kx=SRP         Au=RSA    Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256          TLSv1.2  Kx=DH          Au=DSS    Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384     TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH/ECDSA  Au=ECDH   Enc=AESGCM(256)    Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH/ECDSA  Au=ECDH   Enc=AESGCM(256)    Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384         TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH/ECDSA  Au=ECDH   Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384       TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH/ECDSA  Au=ECDH   Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA            SSLv3    Kx=ECDH/RSA    Au=ECDH   Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA          SSLv3    Kx=ECDH/ECDSA  Au=ECDH   Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA1
AES256-SHA256                  TLSv1.2  Kx=RSA         Au=RSA    Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA256
AES256-SHA                     SSLv3    Kx=RSA         Au=RSA    Enc=AES(256)       Mac=SHA1
RC4-SHA                        SSLv3    Kx=RSA         Au=RSA    Enc=RC4(128)       Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA        SSLv3    Kx=DH          Au=RSA    Enc=Camellia(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA        SSLv3    Kx=DH          Au=DSS    Enc=Camellia(256)  Mac=SHA1
CAMELLIA256-SHA                SSLv3    Kx=RSA         Au=RSA    Enc=Camellia(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA        SSLv3    Kx=DH          Au=RSA    Enc=Camellia(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA        SSLv3    Kx=DH          Au=DSS    Enc=Camellia(128)  Mac=SHA1
CAMELLIA128-SHA                SSLv3    Kx=RSA         Au=RSA    Enc=Camellia(128)  Mac=SHA1
```

Notice all the `ECDHE` ciphers.

However, if I use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html it shows that my server supports(in order of preference):

```
DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 1, Ys: 128)   FS
DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 1, Ys: 128)   FS
DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x67)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 1, Ys: 128)   FS
DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 1, Ys: 128)   FS
DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x6b)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 1, Ys: 128)   FS
DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 1, Ys: 128)   FS
RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c)
RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9d)
RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x3c)
RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)
RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d)
RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)
RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)
DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x88)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 1, Ys: 128)   FS
RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x84)
DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x45)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 1, Ys: 128)   FS
RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x41)
```

Notice there are no `ECDHE` ciphers.

How come Apache is presenting a different list from OpenSSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the httpd [mod_ssl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html) documentation for version 2.2, Eliptic Curve Diffie Hellman Exchanges are not listed as a valid key exchange cipher suite. You can have Anonymous (ADHE) or Ephemeral (EDHE) RSA.

As specified in the documentation for version 2.4 :

> An SSL cipher specification in cipher-spec is composed of 4 major attributes plus a few extra minor ones:
>
> Key Exchange Algorithm:
> RSA, Diffie-Hellman, Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman, Secure Remote Password

as compared to 2.2:

> An SSL cipher specification in cipher-spec is composed of 4 major attributes plus a few extra minor ones:
>
> Key Exchange Algorithm:
> RSA or Diffie-Hellman variants.

Comment: Anyhow, I don't think it's a case of it not supporting that cipher, as much as not knowing about it, therefor not presenting it. That's my opinion though :)

Comment: Interesting. I though that mod_ssl was more or less directly passing all traffic to openssl so it would support everything openssl does.

Comment: Yeah, I guess there is some interpretation going on as well..